# T-SQL writing to a file txt or csv

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, file-io, ole, bcp

I've spent all day scouring the net on answers. Apparently tsql doesn't have its own nifty write to file commands. Here is my dilemma

I have a load file that I am creating where a single line can reach 10K+ in length. On SQL Server varchar(MAX) limit is 8000 (so I believe) so I broke those lines into several variables. I tried to do PRINT but the window pane has allows 4000. The workaround is to print those broken lines one variable at a time but that can get tedious for manual labor so I opted to look into writing it into a txt file one variable at a time.

I looked into BCP via xpcommandshell and it looked promising. Issue was that I could get this line to work on the command prompt yet that exact same line doesn't work on TSQL query:

```
declare @cmd varchar(8000)
select @cmd = 'bcp Client_DB "Select name from dbo.t_TagBuild_set" queryout "Desktop\LAMB\dummy.txt" -c -t, -T'
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

`bcp Client_DB "Select name from dbo.t_TagBuild_set" queryout "Desktop\LAMB\dummy.txt" -c -t, -T` works perfectly fine on command prompt

despite this slight progress, my manager didn't want to go that route. So instead I opted for sp_OACreate and sp_OAMethod after enabling sp_configure via executing this line on SQL:
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1

One of the very first lines on this route is this:

```
EXECUTE @hr = sp_OACreate  'Scripting.FileSystemObject' , @objFileSystem OUT
```

@hr gives a 0 so that's good but @objFileSystem yields 16711422 and @hr eventually becomes -2146828218 which i believe is permissions.

i really am at a loss on finding something simple to do yet i've made this increasingly difficult on myself to find something concrete just to write to a couple variables in a row before adding a new line and repeat the process.

If anyone can expertly help me figure out BCP or sp_OACreate then I'd be very appreciative cause the net as is barely helps (and this is after I spent a lot of time looking through Microsofts own site for an answer)

Comment: `varchar(max)` is "unlimited". `varchar(n)` is limited to n <= 8000.

Comment: *my manager didn't want to go that route.* what your manager's problem with that? Could SSIS do what you need or would your manager nix that as well? Also why are using messing around with FSO? If you're going to that you might as well write a [CLR Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254956%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Technically varchar(max) has a limit of 2gb

Comment: I fiddled with it some more and thought about the permissions issue reagarding sp_OACreate. I experimented and created a folder C:\TestOutput

I went to security properties and gave everyone full control and removed the read-only checkbox. I altered the file path to go to that instead and it now works.

It now dawns on me the permission issue wasn't me but the server itself trying to write into a folder that it didn't have permissions to.

Answer (score 3):

Create a view of your query and select it using `sqlcmd`.

```
declare @cmd varchar(8000)
select @cmd = 'sqlcmd -h-1 -W -S servername -d database -U username -P password -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; select * from VIEW_NAME " -o "C:\OUTPUT\query.csv" '
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

`-h-1` removes the header

`SET NOCOUNT ON` removes the rows affected footer

Comment: you have no idea how your solution helped me! Thanks a ton!!!!

Answer (score 2):

The reason your BCP didn't work is because you were running it from xp_cmdshell with a trusted user.  xp_cmdshell is not run under the user running the script.  You can either a) change your bcp command to use a sql login/password or b) create a job to run it (not xp_cmdshell) because you can control what user it is run as by using run as and a credential.  You can then launch the job within a script by using sp_start_job.

Your other good option is to create an SSIS package and either run it through the command line (say in a bat file) or again run it through a job.

Answer (score 1):

You can write to file on T-SQL using this (it works into trigger):

--char(9) = \t

```
    DECLARE @filename nvarchar(1000);

    SET @filename = ' (echo '+@parameterA+ char(9) +@parameterB+ ... + char(9) +@ParameterN+') > e:\file1.txt && type e:\file1.txt >> e:\file2.txt';

    exec DatabaseName..xp_cmdshell @filename, no_output
```

Comment: @John M I could help you?

Comment: probably the folder needs access from mssqlserver or whatever the service user is.